# How do I force my html page to use the updated included script file?

Tags: javascript, include

I have updated a file included in my html/javascript file

but it keeps using the older version. I have cleared browsing data/cache etc. Checked via the host file editor that the file is updated. Using Chrome and select Empty Cache and Reload. I've tried opening the file in a new tab. Using Chrome Version 89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks

Comment: You could append a parameter to the end of the string like version number like `index.js?v=1.10`

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to completely get rid of caching. it speeds up the loading of pages for returning users.

Nevertheless, you could attach a query parameter to your css/js files so you'd always get a new version whenever you change the query parameter. I suggest you attach your project build number instead of something like a date-timestamp.

example:

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/myapp.js?v=1.2"
```